# How to search in a json array, and return the result as I type in the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So far I can only search an element of the array if I type the exact name present in my api, in this my api has an array with 20 positions and if I type exactly the name of the element I search it returns an array with 19 positions with undefined and 1 position with the array found, what I want to do and search while I type instead of searching only when I type the full name.
After my search I try to change the state of a component so that it is rendered only with the value fetched, but this does not happen, if anyone knows I am very grateful.

```
updated code

 import data from "../sample_data/recipes.json";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchString: data.results })

  }

  onChange(fieldName) {
    if (fieldName === '' || fieldName === null) this.setState({ searchString: data.results });

    var indexes = data.results.filter((item, i) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(fieldName.toLowerCase()) !== -1;    
    })  
    this.setState({ searchString : indexes });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            {<RecipeItem list={this.state.searchString} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you want some kind of filtering while you're typing:

can you try this ? :

```
onChange(fieldName) {
    if (fieldName === '' || fieldName === null) this.setState({ searchString: data.results });

    var filteredItems = data.results.filter((item, i) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(fieldName.toLowerCase()) === -1;    
    })  
    this.setState({ searchString : filteredItems });
  }
```

**Explanation :**

What is requested is to not display items that contains typed letters, to do that, you can use filter items with `filter` method and return only the items which doesn't have the typed letters in the title (using the `indexOf` method).

Comment: Very good, you saved me, you have some link for me to study and understand what you did, I am a beginner...

Comment: First of all there is the documentation, you can watch some crash courses on youtube also, search for academind and traversy media, they have some cool stuff about react and frontend technologies.

Comment: Provide explanation of what was changed. Other than changing variable name this doesn't look any different than what OP had or explain why it would solve problem

Comment: the original code was updated after the answer is accepted, that's way it looks like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- move `setState` outside `map`.
- replace map with for loop

maybe try this?

```js
  var indexes = [];
  data.results.forEach(item => {
   if(item.title.indexOf(myObjTitle.title)) {
    indexes.push(item);
   }
  });
  this.setState({searchString : indexes});
```

Comment: my friend is almost, but the item I search for it disappears from the display screen instead of only the item appears.

Comment: Sorry did not understand you

Comment: In my list I have 20 items right, when I type in my input "item disappears" from my array, getting my array with 19 items.
I'm a beginner, I'm probably explaining in a very wrong way.

Comment: @JanioCarvalho did you use `forEach` instead of `map`?

Comment: Yes, it's like removing my search from the array, leaving only the elements I did not search for.

Comment: @JanioCarvalho can you please update your code with the new version ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to filter the matching results. In which case it's probably better to use `filter` instead of `map`.

```js
onChange(value) {
  let results = [];

  // Empty string is `falsy`, avoid filtering when no value was given
  if (value) {
    /*
      Pick only one option, remove the other two, or you will
      process your data three times instead of once!
    */

    // Case-sensitive, exact match
    results = data.filter(item => item.title === value);

    // Case-insensitive, exact match, value and title are the same when lowercased
    results = data.filter(item => (
      item.title.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()
    ));

    // Case-insensitive, partial match, value was found *within* title
    results = data.filter(item => (
      item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(
        value.toLowerCase()
      ) !== -1
    ));  

  }

  this.setState({results});
}
```

Additionally, if you want a single result (the first one that matches), using `find` instead of `filter` is better, because it would stop searching after the first match instead of traversing the whole array.

#### Map

Returns a new array with as many entries as you previously had, but you may return anything you want as the entries, this is why you get so many `undefined` entries right now. (Because you only return an item when the title matches, hence you implicitly return undefined when not). Map loops through the whole array.

#### Filter

Returns a new array with as many entries matches your test function. If the function returns true, then the item is included, it it returns false, the item will be omitted. Filter loops through the whole array.

#### Find

Will only retrieve the first entry that matches your test function. It will stop looping once a match is found.

#### Bonus

You will most likely need to learn about debouncing, which you can do with [lodash.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce).

Debouncing is a method used to prevent a function from executing many times in a short interval (so you don't unnecessarily re-render)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are trying to search the element from json Array.I just added the new key to store filterString. Here is my solution

```
onChange(firstName){
 if(firstName != undefined){
   this.setState({
    nameToFilter : firstName
   })
 }
}
```

//Inside the render method 
I am using nameToFilter to filter the data.

```
render() {
    let searchString = this.state.searchString
    if(this.state.nameToFilter != undefined && this.state.nameToFilter.length>0)
    {
    searchString = this.state.searchString.filter(item => (
      item.title == this.state.nameToFilter
    ));
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            {<RecipeItem list={searchString} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```